# What's passenger-common for passenger-nginx installation on ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, passenger

We are following the direction [here](http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/nginx-passenger-3-ubuntu-packages) on brightbox.net to install the phusion-passenger on ubuntu 10.04. The `sudo apt-get update` seems fine with the output:

```
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release [14.0kB]
Hit http://apt.brightbox.net lucid Release
Ign http://apt.brightbox.net lucid/main Packages
```

However there is an error for `rvmsudo apt-get install nginx-full`. The error is:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  nginx-full: Depends: passenger-common (< 3.0.10) but 3.0.11+96~lucid1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

We could not find any information about how to install passenger-common.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The package `passenger-common` will be automatically installed as a dependency for `nginx-full` the problem is that the `nginx-full` that you are trying to install has a dependency on version lower then the one that will be installed by this command.

So you will need to take a look at `aptitude` or `synaptic` to determine where this package is coming from and who distributes it and this package will need to be fixed to allow for the later versions of `passenger-common` package if possible.

Comment: The problem seems caused by zlib which was not installed. after installing zlib, the problem disappeared. thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

In my case it was caused by presence of old (apt.brightbox.net) and current (launchpad) brightbox repositories.

After commenting (#) old one at: 
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brightbox.list 
and running apt-get upgrade - everything returned to normal state ;)